# Read each line from a result set and setting the value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table(T1) with userid(int), user_name(char) and contact(char) as columns. 
I need to iterate over the table to find out which user_name is present multiple times in the table and the count. And I will be using the count to delete the user_name if the occurrence is more than three times. 
I tried using

```
select user_name,count(user_name) from T1 group by user_name having count(*)>3

The output is
user_name                     EXPR_1
chris                          4
Fred                           5
```

Now if I need to use the values in EXPR_1. How to iterate over this result set without creating a new/temp table.

Thanks

Comment: What are your desired results?  Are you wanting to delete any records in `T1` that meet this criteria?

Comment: I want to check which user has the highest count in EXPR_1 (more than 3 ). Then  use the username and the count to send it to other application for different purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your query as a sub-select:

```
DELETE FROM T1 WHERE user_name IN (
    SELECT user_name
    FROM T1
    GROUP BY user_name
    HAVING COUNT(user_name) > 3
)
```

---

#### Response to comment:

Well, now I'm confused as to what you're asking for. If all you want to do is sort by highest count, then just do this:

```
SELECT
    user_name,
    COUNT(user_name) AS numOccurrences
FROM T1
GROUP BY user_name
HAVING COUNT(user_name) > 3
ORDER BY numOccurrences DESC
```

Now when you iterate through them, it will be ordered by the number of occurrences, highest to lowest.

Are you asking how to iterate over the results? If so, that completely depends on what tool you're using to execute this query and how you're sending it to your other application. Please elaborate on that.

Comment: I don't want a query to do it. I need the user_name and count from the result set. From result set I need to fetch the user_name and EXPR_1(which is the count) to be sent to different application, which will take care of deleting. Thanks for the query. It is useful.

Comment: Thanks again @Travesty3. The above query gives the result set. I am not able to iterate them. I want to store the result in say set user = user_name; set count_repeats = number of times same user is present; send<user, count_repeats>(internally handled and this code is working fine as hard coding worked);